# call function from same class nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I try to call function from same class but it always return an error `TypeError: this.c is not a function` I tried also `module.exports.c()` and the same result

```
module.exports = (options)=>{
    return{
        a:(a)=>{
           console.log(a);
        },
        b:(b)=>{
          this.c('c');
          console.log(b)
        },
        c:(c)=>{
           console.log(c);
        }
    }
}
```

***After Updated***

```
module.exports =  ({})=>{
    return{
        genereate:function(identifier){
            console.log('genereate')
        },
        middleware:function(req,res,next){
            this.c();
            console.log('genereate')
        },
        c:function(){
            console.log('geeet');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a `Class` it's an `Object` (no `this`)

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions [bind `this` lexically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) (meaning it does not bind it's own `this`). 
Use normal function expressions instead:

```js
module.exports = (options) => {
    return {
        a: function(a){
            console.log(a);
        },
        b: function(b){
            this.c('c');
            console.log(b)
        },
        c: function(c){
            console.log(c);
        }
    };
};
```

---

Browserfied example:

```js
let f = (options) => {
    return {
        a: function(a){
            console.log(a);
        },
        b: function(b){
            this.c('c');
            console.log(b)
        },
        c: function(c){
            console.log(c);
        }
    };
};

f().a("a");
f().b("b");
f().c("c");
```

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo Update your code, like what you tried so that we can help you in fixing it

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo The second code you added is invalid. Working example [here](https://repl.it/repls/LostWillingWebpage).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and export a `class`, just pass `options` to your `constructor`

```js
class InnerCall {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  a(a) {
    console.log(a);
  }

  b(b) {
    this.c('c');
    console.log(b);
  }

  c(c) {
    console.log(c);
  }
}

const example = new InnerCall({ option: 'Im an option' });

example.b('check this out');
console.log(example.options.option);
```

Comment: I need to pass options to InnerCall(options)

Comment: No problem, use `constructor` (I edited the answer)

Comment: thanks Dennis your code work fine but when I have wrote it , show up `TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined ` this error